# Linear Transformation - orthogonal projection and orthogonal symmetry compositions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\vec{a}$ a nonzero vector of $V^2$

I know that orthogonal projection of $\vec{u}$ onto the line generated by $\vec{a} \text{ is}$

$P_{\vec{a}}(\vec{u}) = \frac{(\vec{u}\cdot\vec{a})}{\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}}\vec{a}$

And the orthogonal symmetry relative to line generated by $\vec{a} \text{ is }$

$S_{\vec{a}}(\vec{u}) = 2P_{\vec{a}}(\vec{u}) - \vec{i}d(\vec{u})$

So, how I can calculate?

$P_{\vec{a}} \circ P_{\vec{a}} \text{ and } S_{\vec{a}} \circ S_{\vec{a}}$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orthogonal projection is an idempotent operation.  This means applying it twice is the same as applying it once.  Think intuitively about why this is true.

Then, using this fact, you should be able to show that the orthogonal symmetry you've written down is its own inverse.  There is also intuition as to why this is true (what is the reflection of a reflection?)

To do this computationally, notice that $P_a(u)\cdot a=\frac{u\cdot a}{a\cdot a}a\cdot a=u\cdot a$ so that we have:

$$P_a\circ P_a (u)=\frac{P_a(u)\cdot a}{a\cdot a}a=\frac{u\cdot a}{a\cdot a}a=P_a(u)$$

Using this we have:

$$S_a\circ S_a=(2P_a-\operatorname{id})\circ(2P_a-\operatorname{id})=4P_a\circ P_a-4P_a+\operatorname{id}=\operatorname{id}$$

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is why $P_a(\vec{u})\cdot \vec{a}=\vec{u}\cdot \vec{a}?$

Comment: @user78723: Notice the intermediate step I added

Comment: I did the same here, but I have not seen this
$\frac{u\cdot a}{\color{red}{a\cdot a}} \color{red}{a\cdot a}=u\cdot a$

I'm definitely tired. Thanks again.